# Laravel is not creating RegisterController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller

I installed a few days ago Laravel and I just become aware that RegisterController is not already created.

When I type:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

the RegisterController is still not created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the Authentication scaffolding generated successfully. message after the command. Controller has to be in app/http/controller/auth

Comment: @VaggelisKsps, yes I did, but the only controller created was the HomeController:

C:\wamp\www\laravel>php artisan make:auth
Created View: C:\wamp\www\laravel\resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
...[more created views]....
Created View: C:\wamp\www\laravel\resources/views/welcome.blade.php
Installed HomeController.
Updated Routes File.
Authentication scaffolding generated successfully!

Comment: try a new clean installation maybe something went wrong. I just tried it and all went well.

Comment: @VaggelisKsps, yes, it's a windows machine

Comment: Did you have an auth folder under the controllers folder?

Comment: @VaggelisKsps, yes, I have, but it only has two files: AuthController and PasswordController

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? I think this was happening in older versions. Check your version in the composer.json at the root of your project folder

Comment: @VaggelisKsps, I installed it a few days ago:

php artisan --version returns Laravel Framework version 5.2.45

Comment: The current version is 5.7. If you are using global laravel installer you have to update your installer or just use composer create-project laravel/laravel nameofyourproject .Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#installation)